# How to use IIS and Glassfish/Tomcat in the same server?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, iis, glassfish

Here is my problem:

My company has a server with **IIS** and i wasnt abble to install **GlassFish** there because it may cause problems with **IIS** and all other pages that are there. So I could use **Tomcat** too but it seams will have the same problems. **GlassFish/Tomcat** will want to listen to the same *port* as **IIS** and the only thing I can do is to have both (IIS and GlassFish/Tomcat) at the same time in the same saver.

I have a **Java Web Application** that I want to put there but... dont know how to install **GlassFish/Tomcat without** afecting **IIS**.

Please explain me how to do it.

Comment: You move it to a different (non-default) port.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: Try a Google search. There are plenty of results with step-by-step instructions on how to change the port number for either server.